# Is this Illustrator gradient editable?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient-mesh

I have a background gradient that I imported into Illustrator, from an EPS file that I got.

I am not sure if it is actually editable. It seems to be a group with a mesh.

Is there a specific way of editing such an object's gradient or is this most likely a raster image?

Apologies for the naivety

[image]

Comment: It's not raster.. it's called a **Gradient Mesh** and it is vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the 'A' direct selection tool to click on each of the mesh points - you will then be able to change their color. This could be a tedious process, but you can lasso-select many points at a time of same color to change several points at once.
If you would like to keep the color relationships in the mesh but change the overall color similar to Photoshop's Hue/Saturation sliders, you can have the entire mesh selected and then use the Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork menu item.